# PDF documents are not opening for FBA logged in user only on android devices from SharePoint 2013 public site

Tags: forms-authentication, mobile

We have a public facing SharePoint 2013 site with Form based authentication set up, this site has document library which contains pdf files.

These pdf files are opening fine from laptops(all the browsers),iphones,ipads but not from any android devices for logged in users and gives 'can not open file, invalid file format' error.

If I set anonymous access on this document library then pdf files can open fine from android devices as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,